'$n\times p$' passengers in '$n$' identical boats (which can accommodate '$p$' passengers each)
There are $n$ identical boats and each boat can accommodate $p$ passengers. What are the total number of ways $n\cdot p$ passengers can be accommodated in $n$ boats?
Here's my approach to solve the question:
Step 1: Consider each boat and each seat unique, so total unique seats are '$n\cdot p$',$$Arrangements = (n.p)!$$
Step 2: Eliminate the uniqueness of all boats, make them identical,$$Arrangements = {(n.p)!\over n!}$$
Step 3: Eliminate the uniqueness of all the seats in each boat,$$Arrangements = {(n.p)!\over n!\times (p!)^n}$$
So, the answer should be $= {(n.p)!\over n!\times (p!)^n}$
Is the approach and answer right? Please do comment any mistakes or improvement in solution or approach.

Hi and welcome to the site! It is advisable that you take a tour to see what we are about. Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "avoiding no-clue questions").

Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

@5xum Thank you so much for your guidance. I am new to using stack exchange and I had no idea we were supposed to add our thoughts too. In fact I came to a solution and I am so willing to discuss if its correct or wrong or a bad approach. Give me some minutes I'll edit and add my approach of solving it.

@IshantDumane: Your answer is correct, perhaps you could conceptualise it more simply as forming $n$ unlabeled teams of $p$ people each.

I assume that each boats behaves like a set so it does not matter the order in which I place the $n$ persons in each boat.
Let $A(n,p)$ be the number of ways to assign the total of $n*p$ persons to the boats.
First, notice that A(1,p) = 1 since the p persons fits in exactly one way in a $p$-persons boat.
If you have $n > 1$ boats. We can assign $\binom{np}{p}$ to the first boat and we are left with $n - 1$ boats with $p$ seats in each. We can solve the rest of the possibilities in this recursive fashion: $A(n,p) = \binom{np}{p} A(n-1,p)$. Now that we have a recursive solution, we can try to expand it to deduce a closed formula:
$A(n,p) = \dbinom{np}{p}A(n-1,p) = \dbinom{np}{p}\dbinom{(n-1)p}{p}A(n-2,p) = \dbinom{np}{p}\dbinom{(n-1)p}{p}\dbinom{(n-2)p}{p}A(n-3,p) = \dots = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\dbinom{(n-i)p}{p}$

I did edited it and added my approach to solve it. I am sorry for earlier posting a raw question since I am new to using stack, I don't know the community and culture well here. Thank you

@trueblueanil The posted edited their question

I think your solution is wrong. Since there will be repetitions when you use that decution formula.

@Gauss 'n Roses: Your answer is incorrect as you have worked out an answer for labeled boats (=labeled teams) whereas they are unlabeled, and so you should amend
